# Scalr image resize changes background color on output

Tags: java, image, resize, image-resizing, imgscalr

I am using Scalr to resize images. I have a problem with some images. Scalr is changing the color of the resized image.
In short, this is the outline of my code.
I read the file from byte array:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bis);
```

Then I resize the image using scalr:

```
Scalr.resize(image,
      Scalr.Method.ULTRA_QUALITY, Scalr.Mode.AUTOMATIC, targetWidth, targetHeight);
```

Then, I write it to output file:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, extension, baos);
```

The type of the image before and after resizing is same and equals to TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR.

Original image:

[image: original image]

Image after resize:

[image: image after resizing]

Comment: try to use "png" as extension

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. To solve this problem you should drop the alpha channel of the image if it exists.

```
public BufferedImage dropAlphaChannel(BufferedImage src) {
 BufferedImage convertedImg = new BufferedImage(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
 convertedImg.getGraphics().drawImage(src, 0, 0, null);
 return convertedImg;
}

if (originalImage.getColorModel().hasAlpha()) {
   originalImage = dropAlphaChannel(originalImage);
}
```

[Ref](https://github.com/rkalla/imgscalr/issues/82#issuecomment-11776976)